# React Native Touchable on press down event

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a component similar to TouchableHighlight, but instead of highlighting the background I want to highlight text. I need to hook into the onPress event that fires at the point the user actually presses.

I've tried using TouchableWithoutFeedback and onPressIn, but it doesn't seem to fire. Here is the code I've been testing with.

```
class TouchableTextHighlight extends React.Component {

constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        isHighlighted: false
    }
}

highlight () {
    console.log('pressed')
    this.setState({
        isHighlighted: true
    })
}

render () {
    let textColor = this.state.isHighlighted ? '#F44336' : null

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...this.props} onPressIn={() => {this.highlight}} onPress={this.props.onPress}>
            <View {...this.props}>
                <Text
                style={[this.props.textStyle, {color: textColor}]}
                >{this.props.text}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke the method. Change:

```
onPressIn={() => {this.highlight}}
```

to

```
onPressIn={() => {this.highlight()}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is perfectly fine but you missed one thing which is very important to understand- `Binding functions`. Your`highlight` function not bound to the context. There are many ways to bind the function but here I will tell about one way which is efficient.

```
highlight () {
console.log('pressed')
this.setState({
    isHighlighted: true
})
}
```

rewrite above function like this

```
highlight = () => {
console.log('pressed')
this.setState({
    isHighlighted: true
})
}
```

If you want to read more about binding in `react` [check out here](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html)